# Using percent signs in objective c (Not modulo)

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I would like to know what percents mean in objective c/c.

For example:

printf("x is equal to %d.\n", x);

The following example works... but I would like to know how to use all of the %letters correctly. I know they also have to do with it being 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ or http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a the initial part of a format specifier.

Characters in the format string are usually copied literally into the function's output, as is usual for templates, with the other parameters being rendered into the resulting text in place of certain placeholders – points marked by format specifiers, which are typically introduced by a `%` character, though syntax varies. 
width ,precision,output formatting everything can be done on this .

Different types of format specifiers are possible and any good reference on `printf` should detail them.

Comment: Thanks... This almost answered my question. I was just wondering the different types of percent signs. Ie: %d , %a , %o

Answer (score 1):

That is [formatted output](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/formatted_io.html) and the percent sign is used to begin a formatting specification. From the given link,

> ```
> %<flags><field width><precision><length>conversion
> ```
>
> The meaning of flags, field width, precision, length, and conversion are given below, although tersely. For more detail, it is worth looking at what the Standard says.
>
> flags
>
> ```
> Zero or more of the following:
>
> -
>     Left justify the conversion within its field.
> +
>     A signed conversion will always start with a plus or minus sign.
> space
>     If the first character of a signed conversion is not a sign, 
> insert a space. Overridden by + if present.
> #
>    Forces an alternative form of output. The first digit of an 
>    octal conversion will always be a 0; inserts 0X in front of a non-zero 
>    hexadecimal conversion; forces a decimal point in all floating point
>    conversions even if one is not necessary; does not remove trailing
>    zeros from g and G conversions.
>  0
>    Pad d, i, o, u, x, X, e, E, f, F and G conversions on the left with 
>    zeros up to the field width. Overidden by the - flag. If a precision 
>    is specified for the d, i, o, u, x or X conversions, the flag is
>    ignored. The behaviour is undefined for other conversions.
> ```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments by [@stevesliva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3120884/stevesliva), you might also find the [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) in the IOS core documentation for Objective C.

Comment: Ought to add the [Objective C reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) as well.